# How to find a custom tag within another tag using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
<div class="myclass">    
<a href="example.com" class="link"  content="This is my content" </a>
</div>
```

Using Selenium (Python), I will like to find the value of `content`. I tried using `find_element_by_tag_name` but it seems not to work.

Comment: It doesn't work because `content` is not an _element/tag_.  It is an _attribute_ on the `a` element/tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="myclass"]/a').get_attribute("content")
```

Comment: Thanks. I just learned the easiest way is that to inspect the element using Chrome Developer tool and copy the XPath

Answer (score 1):

```
find_elements_by_css_selector('div.myclass > a').get_attribute('content')
```

This is much cleaner than xpath.  CSS is also faster and more readable than xpath. I'd recommend using this.